# Is there any way to speed up a query with 3x UNION on the same large table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, union

Assuming that the following query is legitimate and executes successfully, is there any way to speed it up?

```
SELECT foo from T1 --T1 is a huge (>5e6 rows) table with no indexes
UNION
SELECT bar from T1
UNION
SELECT baz from T1
UNION
SELECT qux from T1
```

The four columns shown above are all of type `nvarchar(128)`, non-sparse and nullable. I am using SQL Server 2008. Thanks!

**EDIT:** Provided more info. I cannot add indices because it is a Stage table. Also, removing the `DISTINCT`s; I totally forgot about that.

Phil: How do I consolidate this into a single query?

Comment: Consolidate into a single query if they're all coming from the same table? Hard to advise without query plans etc

Comment: Also your `DISTINCT`s are uneeded - a `UNION` will filter out duplicates from the final result set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are alternatives to [@Remus Rusanu's CROSS APPLY suggestion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21726/6965). Even though I myself incline to using CROSS APPLY for your kind of problem, I think it may be worth knowing about other ways of achieving the same result without introducing multiple scans of the same table.

1. `UNPIVOT`:

   ```
   WITH selectedcolumns AS (
     SELECT foo, bar, baz, qux FROM T1
   )
   SELECT DISTINCT v
   FROM selectedcolumns
   UNPIVOT (
     v FOR colname IN (foo, bar, baz, qux)
   ) u
   ;
   ```
2. `CROSS JOIN` to an inline view (essentially a pre-`UNPIVOT` method of unpivoting):

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT
     v = CASE x.i
       WHEN 1 THEN foo
       WHEN 2 THEN bar
       WHEN 3 THEN baz
       WHEN 4 THEN qux
     END
   FROM T1
   CROSS JOIN (
     VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)
     -- or SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL ... in 2005 and older versions
   ) x (i)
   ;
   ```

The latter seems least attractive to me of the three (including CROSS APPLY) methods, but I still think it may be useful to know about it as a pattern to recognise in older scripts, so that you can transform it to a probably more efficient CROSS APPLY or, where more suitable, UNPIVOT.

Comment: Andriy, the two examples return different rowcounts. The `UNPIVOT` example returns one less row than the `CROSS JOIN` example. What could be the possible reasons? **EDIT:** It is because `CROSS JOIN` has a `NULL` record, whereas the `UNPIVOT` example does not. =)

Comment: Ah, indeed, I forgot about NULLs. Thanks for finding that out and sharing the results! By the way, in view of your find, do you think CROSS APPLY would be more suitable than either of the methods mentioned in my answer? I mean, it would return the same results as the CROSS JOIN method but it would likely be more efficient (even if just slightly). (In case you are still struggling with the correct syntax: `SELECT DISTINCT v FROM T1 CROSS APPLY (VALUES (foo), (bar), (baz), (qux)) x (v);`.)

Answer (score 7):

You can certainly project `foo`, `bar`, `baz` and `qux` in a single scan (`SELECT foo, bar, baz, qux FROM T1`).  A `CROSS APPLY` TVF can transform each row (4 columns) into 4 rows (1 column) and then apply DISTINCT on top. If the original plan had 4 scans of T1 which would dominate the cost, this may be better.

Comment: +1, but did you really mean a TVF? A simple `CROSS APPLY (SELECT foo UNION ALL SELECT bar UNION ALL ...)` would seem to me enough.

Comment: @AndriyM: I reckon I haven't thought about your proposed improvement. Sure, it would be better than a TVF. In my defense I was writing the response from my Mac and I didn't bother to fire up a VM to test it... if being lazy is an acceptable defense ;)

Comment: If nothing else, it's a kind of defence that suits me perfectly at the moment. :) I only wanted to make sure I got the general idea (which, incidentally, I find brilliant) right.

Comment: Remus, Andriy: Thank you both for your comments. I am a SQL newbie and have never used CROSS APPLY before. Reading the Online Help in SSMS, I don't yet fully understand what it does. Can you please provide the full syntax?